# Flagging Calls In SQL (Hive)

Tags: sql, hive, flags

I have a dataset below that I need to flag these calls as shown in field Call_CA with this condition in SQL (Hive).

From same phone number, for calls that have been dialed to other LOBs before calling CA, flag these call as BEFORE. And for calls that have been dialed to other LOBs after calling CA, flag these calls as AFTER.

Would you please let me know how to do this?

Thank you for your help everyone.

```
gen_source_address  Called_Time LOB Call_CA
2012123923  3/20/2015 18:10:00  ca  
2012123923  3/20/2015 18:15:00  cl  After
2012123923  4/20/2015 11:30:00  ca  
2012123923  4/20/2015 11:31:00  ca  
2012123923  4/20/2015 11:39:00  cl  After
2012123923  4/20/2015 15:36:00  cl  After
2012123923  4/27/2015 12:40:00  cl  After
2012123923  4/28/2015 10:07:00  cl  After
2012123923  4/28/2015 11:58:00  cl  After
2012136626  1/10/2015 16:02:00  ca  
2012146914  11/23/2014 10:57:00 pl  Before
2012146914  11/23/2014 11:04:00 claim   Before
2012146914  12/1/2014 18:19:00  ca  
2012181514  7/20/2015 16:20:00  ca  
2012181514  7/20/2015 16:24:00  pl  After
2012183018  3/17/2015 11:01:00  pl  Before
2012183018  3/17/2015 11:28:00  pl  Before
2012183018  3/17/2015 11:37:00  pl  Before
2012183018  4/8/2015 16:50:00   ca  
2012183018  4/8/2015 16:52:00   pl  After
2012201789  11/15/2014 1:30:00  claim   Before
2012201789  11/15/2014 1:55:00  ca  
2012201789  11/15/2014 0:30:00  claim   After
2012204480  1/10/2015 16:47:00  ca  
2012204480  1/10/2015 16:48:00  pl  After
2012223263  1/17/2015 10:54:00  ca  
2012223263  1/17/2015 10:58:00  pl  After
2012223263  4/4/2015 11:58:00   pl  After
2012223263  12/21/2014 11:28:00 pl  After
```

Comment: Nothing in your data is called "phone number" or "calls" or "dialed".  Hence, your question makes no sense.

Comment: sorry the gen_source_address  field is phone number.